# EntityFramework 'join' with fixed value segments in a composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Currently for EF5, but planning to upgrade to EF6 'soon'.

With following Tables:
Note these tables are simplified to explain the issue, the real tables are obviously more complex.  The database is a legacy database and I can't change the tables.
BarRed and BarBlue are different tables with a different structure, only the way they link to Foo is identical.

```
[Table("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    // Id+ColorCode is the primary Key on this table
    [Key,Column(Order=0)]
    int Id;
    [Key,Column(Order=1)]
    int ColorCode;  // 1=red, 2=blue, 3=green, …

    public virtual ICollection<BarRed> BarRed { get; set; } // when ColorCode==1, empty/null otherwise
    public virtual ICollection<BarRed> BarBlue { get; set; } // when ColorCode==2, empty/null otherwise
}

[Table("BarRed")]
public class BarRed
{
    [Key]
    int Id; // Id is the primary key in this table.
    // There is no ColorCode column in this table, essentially the ColorCode for each record in this table is the literal value 1.

    [ForeignKey("Id,1")]    // This doesn't work, doesn't accept the 1
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

[Table("BarBlue")]
public class BarBlue
{
    [Key]
    int Id; // Id is the primary key in this table.
    // There is no ColorCode column in this table, essentially the ColorCode for each record in this table is the literal value 2.

    [ForeignKey("Id,2")]    // This doesn't work, doesn't accept the 2
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

So in short, how do I get EntityFramework to link 2 tables in a One-To-Many relation when the 'Many' side table doesn't have an explicit column for one of the key segments, but a fixed literal value should be used on all rows.

I also have a similar issue/problem in the other direction, a One-To-Many where the 'One'  side doesn't have an explicit column on each record but a literal value should be used.

I can join the tables from SQL and this does work and uses the indexes properly, I need this for EF to make the database accessible from OData.